# PHP Fake Mailer Script says 'via' or 'on behalf of'

Tags: php, email

I am using a php fake mailer script and I was wondering if I could get rid of the 'via' and 'on behalf of message that the receiver gets?

Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST['Submit'] == 'Send')
{
if (strcmp(md5($_POST['user_code']),$_SESSION['ckey']))
    { 
header("Location: sendmail.php?msg=ERROR: Invalid Verification Code");
exit();
  } 

$to = $_POST['toemail'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$fromemail = $_POST['fromemail'];
$fromname = $_POST['fromname'];
$lt= '<';
$gt= '>';
$sp= ' ';
$from= 'From:';
$headers = $from.$fromname.$sp.$lt.$fromemail.$gt;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header("Location: sendmail.php?msg= Mail Sent!");
exit();
}
?>
```

The rest of the code is just the html text boxes.

This is what I am getting on the receivers side:

**GMail:**
from@example.com via srv35.main-hosting.eu

**Outlook:**
u637630352@srv35.main-hosting.eu; on behalf of; Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add SPF and DKIM records to your sending domains to remove the 'on behalf of' or 'via' information. More detail in this link

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582277-How-do-I-add-DNS-records-for-my-sending-domains-

Comment: Would you be able to write a sample code of how to use this feature please?

Comment: which web hosting service are you using ?

Comment: I have tried using v=spf1 include:spf.mx.hostinger.com ~all, but when I send an email using php, it still says via srv35.main-hosting.eu?

Comment: have you configured DKIM Record ??